# EF power tools beta 3 error while using Generate View

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-power-tools

Recently I have migrated to EF6 alpha 3 and when I use EF Power Tools Beta 3 for "Generate Views" for my context to get faster startup , I get this error message :

```
---------------------------
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---------------------------
```

I was using it before migration without any problem.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I had the same issue, and posted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959529/generating-code-first-views-with-oracle It may help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code first approach then make sure your DbContext class must have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: In my last version code it didn't have such a constructor but it was working well, anyway now I am using Threading for fetching first query from DB and it works fine. Thanks